# ASIFormDataRequest Upload Image From a URL

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

Can you directly upload an image from a URL or from a site using ASIFormDataRequest? like this?

```
[request setFile:@"http://www.someKindOfSite.com/folder/folder/imageHere.jpg" forKey:@"image"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, you have to download the file first and then upload it. Unless the server side code that receives the upload would accept a URL as a parameter and download the file itself.

Comment: when downloading the image do i have to use ASIHTTPRequest or can I just use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"imageURLAgainHere"]]; ? I'm not sure if that works, or is there an easier way?

Comment: I can't say for sure this works, as the documentation isn't clear, but I'd rather do it with ASIHTTPRequest as you can make it asynchronous without having to care about it, while dataWithContentsOfURL seems to be a synchronous call.